# How to see the old log files in PCF?

Tags: pcf, pcfdev

I may be asking some basic question but I am not able to find any information. I know to view the log files in PCF i can use

```
cf logs and cf logs --recent
```

The issue with this is it will send only the recent log files. I want to get the archive log file from PCF for my jobs, is there a way to get those information?

Comment: Please share the answer if you found it. !

Comment: We can get the logs from PCF matrix page and top select the old logs using the timeline slider.